# Issues with Copy-item script

Tags: powershell, scripting

I have a script that needs to copy a list of files to ceraitn directories and locations on target servers.
I was able to understand that I need to creat an csv file as follows:

[image: source & dest CSV]

I need to understand from you how to make the files from source location to their adjacent file in target location. Any ideas?

My code looks like this:

```cs
 # customize log file
$date = (Get-Date -Format d).ToString() | foreach {$_ -replace "/", "_"}
$time = (Get-Date)

$scriptDir = "D:\Scripts\ServerBuildToolkitT1\SingleFileUpfate\"
$logDir = "D:\Scripts\ServerBuildToolkitT1\Logs\SingleFileUpfate\"

$logFileName = "SingleFileUpfate $date.log"

$sources = @()
$destinsyions = @()

function CSV {
    Import-Csv D:\Scripts_PS\SD.csv | ForEach-Object {
        $sources += $_."Source Location"
        $destinations += $_."Destination Location"
    }
}

# this file contains the list of destination server that you want copy
# file/folder to
$computers = Get-Content "D:\Scripts_PS\ServerList.txt"

function main 
{
    foreach ($computer in $computers) {
        foreach ($destination in $destinations) {

        Write-Output "$([DateTime]::Now) Copying files update to $computer now" |
            Out-File -FilePath "$logDir\$logFileName" -Append
        Copy-Item $sources -Destination "\\$computer\$destination" -Force -Recurse -Verbose:$false
    }
}
}

csv
main

Write-Output "$([DateTime]::Now) the operation SingleFileUpdate completed successefully" |
    Out-File -FilePath "$logDir\$logFileName" -Append
```

i have updtaed the Script (as seen above) and now i am getting the following ERROR
"WARNING: One or more headers were not specified. Default names starting with "H" have been used in place of any missing headers."

Comment: Your function `CSV` tries to append to a variables `$source` and `$destination` that you didn't define, the function `main` uses variables `$sources` and `$destinations` that you didn't define, and the loop `foreach ($destination in $destinations)` is broken (missing loop body).

Comment: can you give more pointers on how to fix this?

Comment: i have edited the script, what do you think?

Comment: Appending to `$sources` and `$destinations` should now work, although appending to arrays in a loop is not the most efficient thing to do. The innermost `foreach` loop in the `main` function is still lacking a body. Please take a look at the [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_foreach?view=powershell-3.0).

Comment: Hi Ansgar, can you be more specific on what is missing?

Comment: i read the article haven't seen anything new there

Comment: Please pay attention to the syntax. The structure of a `foreach` loop is `foreach ($var in $list) {...}`. Note the curly brackets.

Comment: i saw that allready and fixed it.

Comment: i am still getting an error "WARNING: One or more headers were not specified. Default names starting with "H" have been used in place of any missing headers." any idea?

Comment: Please update your question with the code you currently have and the complete error message.

Comment: I have updated the code and the error i get

Comment: Please copy/paste the complete error message, including line number and stacktrace.